# CRC32 Parameters Reverse Engineering having access to multiple examples

Tags: reverse-engineering, crc, crc32

I have to find out how to reproduce the CRC32 algorithm used on a proprietary database file, the file consists of many "chunks" of 128 bytes, each being a record. I know that for each record, bytes 1-4 are the CRC32 Checksum, and the next 35 bytes don't seem to matter, as I can change them easily without the application telling me the CRC Check has failed. Therefore, I am looking to find out what polynomial and other parameters are being used to calculate the latter. Below is an example.

[image: Real Example of a record]
Text version:

```
00 27 AE 3B 9F 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 41 08 41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41 
19 42 42 42 42 42 42 42 42 42 42 42 42 42 42 42 42 42 42 42 42 42 42 42 42 
42 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00
```

If we take just the bytes we can't change, breaking the record, we get this:

```
41 08 41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41 19 42 42 42 42 42 42 42 42 42 42 42 42 42 42 
42 42 42 42 42 42 42 42 42 42 42 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

the CRC32 for the above is **27 AE 3B 9F**

*Real Record Example 1.1, differing only by one byte from the above* (CRC is **BC D4 84 FB**):

```
41 08 41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41 19 42 42 42 42 42 42 42 42 42 42 42 42 42 42 42 
42 42 42 42 42 42 42 42 42 43 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

*Real Record Example 2* (Output CRC is **3B 6A D1 AF**):

```
41 07 41 41 41 41 41 41 41 00 19 42 42 42 42 42 42 42 42 42 42 42 42 42 42 42 
42 42 42 42 42 42 42 42 42 42 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

*Real Record Example 3* (Output CRC is **0B 54 CC 09**):

```
41 01 31 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 03 41 73 61 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

*Real Record Example 4* (Output CRC is **12 91 EA 8E**):

```
41 B4 A8 D0 02 46 00 B4 A8 00 03 52 4D 31 03 53 54 50 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 FF 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 25 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 A3 05 00 00 00 64 00 64 00 64 00 64 00 64 00 64 00 64 00 64 00 64 00 64 
00 64 00 64 00 64 00 64 00 64 00 64 00 64 00 64 00 64 00 64 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

*Real Record Example 5* (Output CRC is **8A 68 00 3B**):

```
41 B4 A8 D0 02 46 00 B4 A8 01 03 52 4D 31 03 53 54 50 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 FF 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 25 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 A3 05 00 00 00 64 00 64 00 64 00 64 00 64 00 64 00 64 00 64 00 64 00 64 
00 64 00 64 00 64 00 64 00 64 00 64 00 64 00 64 00 64 00 64 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

The two last records differ on only one byte. By using the approach @rcgldr specified, I was able to get a final Xor value of **0x9902539d** and I could successfully change data without the application complaining. I ran some code to find these final xor values for every entitity/file on the application and was successful on all of them, but being able to find a single crc parameter set would be a great addition.

EDIT: Added two more example records

EDIT 2: Added one more example that only differs from one byte comparing to the first one

EDIT 3: Added two more examples, with a different size, as their from another type of record within the application. Also deleted part of the question as it became irrelevant

Comment: If you have formula, input and output values, you can use SMT solver to find out unknown coefficients in the formula.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I follow that XOR'ing the two records thing, any place I can see this illustrated in action? Thanks for the answers, by the way, I'll keep on researching how to get this done on the meanwhile.

Comment: It would help to post more example records, especially with minimal differences between two records. If you could find two records that are the same except for the crc and one byte in the data, the xor'ing those two records would simplify trying to reverse engineer the CRC, since there are ways to speed up generating test case crc's when there are a lot of zeroes, or best case, a single non-zero byte in the data.

Comment: Thanks, just added two more example records.

Comment: The 0x19 and 0x03 respectively are just the size of the attribute, so for the first two records, we can parse that value to a string consisting of 25 Bs, and the last example just translates to "AsA". These are just values that you see on the application that reads this file.

Comment: If It helps, I can provide examples with more concrete data, instead of just saving gibberish. Thanks in advance

Comment: Added a new example (1.1) where only one byte changes, a B to a C (0x42 --> 0x43).

Comment: @rchldr if you mean the last byte of the block (byte number 87), I can't. Would have to do it manually but it breaks the CRC. There's nowhere I can go on the application that writes that specific byte.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

xor'ing 1.0 and 1.1 results in:

```
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

xor'ing the two crcs results in

```
9b 7a bf 64
```

Assuming "little endian" for the stored crc, the calculated crc is

```
0x64bf7a9b
```

By xor'ing two records, the initial value and final xor value are canceled out due to the xor, which allows the crc polynomial to be determined based on the data alone, assuming that initial value = 0 and that final xor value = 0. Taking advantage of this, I tried some common crc polynomials and determined that the crc polynomial is

```
0x104C11DB7 or ignoring the msb: 0x04C11DB7
```

Using this web site that you linked to in your comment:

http://www.sunshine2k.de/coding/javascript/crc/crc_js.html

The parameters are:

```
crc32
custom
input:  not reflected
result: not reflected
polynomial: 0x04C11DB7
initial value: 0x0
final xor value: 0x0
```

If the data is always the same size, then either the initial value or the final xor value or a combination of both can be used to adjust the crc so that it matches the actual crc's shown in the examples, but it is simplest to use the final xor to match the examples, since it just requires calculating a crc with one of the examples, assuming initial value = 0 and final xor value = 0, then xor'ing the calculated crc with the actual crc from the example crc to calculate a final xor value for a specific length of data.

So for the data size in the first examples, a final xor value of 0x189B52BC will produce crc's that match the examples. These are the parameters for the crc calculator.

```
crc32
custom
input:  not reflected
result: not reflected
polynomial: 0x04C11DB7
initial value: 0x0
final xor value: 0x189B52BC
```

These parameters match all of the first examples you posted. Again, note that the crc's are stored "little endian", most significant byte first.

If the data size is variable, then an initial value is needed (and it's possible both an initial value and final xor value are used). Once the polynomial is known, it's possible to do a "reverse" CRC to find the initial value, or a brute force search can be used. I did a brute force search for an initial value using a fast crc calculator (since I don't have a "reverse" CRC program yet), and it appears that it will work for any data size, at least based on the new examples you added. These parameters work with all of the examples above, include the new ones you added:

```
crc32
custom
input:  not reflected
result: not reflected
polynomial: 0x04C11DB7
initial value: 0xc704dd7b
final xor value: 0x0
```

The initial value of 0xc704dd7b is the crc that is generated with a data pattern of {ff ff ff ff}, with initial value = 0 and final xor value = 0. It's the same as prefixing the data with {ff ff ff ff}.

Comment: Using [link](http://www.sunshine2k.de/coding/javascript/crc/crc_js.html) I changed the polynomial to **0x6485409B** and no luck there. Then I added a record manually on the file and it said invalid CRC

Comment: @marcoscaramalho - I updated my answer. You can try other examples to verify I got the correct values to use.

Comment: Hello, I can confirm it works, THANKS!!, but I have a question if you'd be so kind to answer. I don't follow the last step to calculate the final xor value, what exactly did you XOR to get that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thank you @rcgldr I understand it now, I wrote a small program that does this work for me, as I noticed that for other files within the application they use different final xor values. The app is huge, and I needed some way to automate this process. Once again, thank you very much for the help, I learned a ton.

Comment: @marcoscaramalho -  I did a brute force search to find initial value 0xc704dd7b, final xor value = 0x0, which should work with any data size. This should work for any data size. I updated my answer.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in giving feedback, I confirm it works for any data size, once again thank you for your time, this was giving me a big headache and I can't emphasize how much I learned from this